# does flutter respect border radius of parent?

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a stateless widget with this builder function:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: widget.position.dy, left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 200),
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 60, color: Color(0x8500ffff)),
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

basically one `ListView` inside a `Container` widget. the Container has `BorderRadius.circular(20)`. The list vie item is a simple `Container`.

Now - when I scroll the list view, the border radius of the parent container is not respected.

[image]

Is that correct behaviour or do I make a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: see [Container#decoration](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart#L320)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `borderRadius` for your `listview` children widgets, I faced the same issue before and I managed to solve it by doing that. So you should modify your `ListView` widget:

```
 child: ListView(
 padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
 shrinkWrap: true,
 children: <Widget>[
   Container(
 height: 60,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
 color: Color(0x8500ffff)),
 ), 
 ],
),
```

Comment: this would be a different layout than I'd like to achieve. In your answer, the list view is still rectangular, I need the border radius on the list view, itself.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this now, you need to wrap your `ListView` in a `ClipRRect` with the same border radius as your parent container

So something like this should work:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: widget.position.dy, left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 200),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(height: 60, color: Color(0x8500ffff)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that one neat way of doing it.